# Enviar dados evento fullcalendar para janela modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal, fullcalendar

Tenho um fullcalendar com os seguintes eventos:

```
events: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Evento 01',
      start: '2020-02-06'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Evento 02',
      start: '2020-02-19'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Evento 03',
      start: '2020-02-25'
    }
]
```

Quando clicamos no evento uma modal é exibida:

```
eventClick:  function(event) {
    var id = event.event.id;
    $('#modal').modal();
}
```

Externamente, de forma desacoplada, um outro js, específico para essa finalidade, se encarrega de carregar os dados na modal via ajax:

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    //Ajax
});
```

Como posso enviar os dados de "event" da function "eventClick" para o js que chama o ajax quando a janela modal é aberta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei encontrando a solução setando o atributo data-id:

```
eventClick:  function(event) {
    $('#modal').attr('data-id', event.event.id).modal();
}
```

E pegando essa informação no outro documento:

```
('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    //Ajax
});
```